# SQL Server Management Studio: Open table for Editing through keyboard shortcut

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, keyboard-shortcuts, ssms

While using SQL Server Management Studio (2008), is it possible to open a table in Edit mode through keyboard shortcut or even some special keyword I type while in "New Query" window?

Comment: we've come a long way from only having the command line and vi

Comment: But damn microsoft decided we need to buttons, "Select rows from table" & "edit rows from table"... damn them...

Comment: I can honestly say that I hardly ever (one time every 5 years if that) "edit" data in any database using SSMS. When I need to make changes I use INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE.  Data changes should be done by an application.  I know in older versions (like SQL Server 7), you could lock/block other users by having the edit table window displayed.

Comment: @KM. it's a useful feature during development when you need to tweak rows and see the effects on your page/application.

Comment: I see where the he is coming from with this. but during my search for the tool/shortcut, all I found was this post. A nice feature would be an edit command followed by the table name would trigger the edit top 200 window to open. (Intellisense for the table name would also be nice).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No this can't be done.

Answer (score 3):

You can open a table by right clicking on the table you want to edit and selecting "edit all rows" - before doing this make sure your options are set tools/options/ Sql server object explorer/commands.

Dont know if that helps but maybe.

Comment: Then you can right click on the results then select Pane>SQL. Then you can change your query at will.