# Open Rows For Edit using TSQL in SQL SERVER similar to Oracle SELECT ... FOR UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

For editing table Rows in SQL Serever we do a right click and Edit Top 200 Rows. But it will be tedious if you have lot of tables. Is there is any TSQL command out there to open open rows for editing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764587/sql-server-management-studio-open-table-for-editing-through-keyboard-shortcut

Comment: You need to use a different SQL client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. TSQL is a "backend" language. "Edit Top 200 Rows" is a frontend feature of SSMS.